# compare two record sets in vb6

Tags: vb6

I have two recordsets rs1 and rs2 in vb6. i want to compare each record in rs1 with each record in rs2. If `rtn(column)` in rs1 is same as in rtn in rs2.then `set date = now` and `claim = c`.

This is what I want to do. How to compare each row in rs1 with each row in rs2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop over both recordsets in an inner and outer loop similar to the following

```
rs1.MoveFirst
While not rs1.EOF
    rs2.MoveFirst 
    While not rs2.EOF
        'Do your comparisons here'
         if rs1("colum").value = rs2("column").value then
            'do other stuff
         end if  
        rs2.MoveNext
    Wend
rs1.MoveNext
Wend
```

If you need to compare each field you can iterate over the fields similar to the following
This assumes the recordsets have the same fields in the same order

```
Dim i as integer
for i = 0 to rs1.Fields.Count -1
  if rs.fields(i).Value = rs2.fields(i).value then
      'DO other stuff'
  End if
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

A much better solution would be to do the comparison in the Query/SQL instead of the code such that each mismatched row is returned from a single query.

For example

```
SELECT T1.*,T2.* 
FROM T1,T2
WHERE (T1.ID=T2.ID) AND 
     ((T1.Field1<>T2.Field1) OR (T1.Field2<>T2.Field2) ...)
```