# MS Access Form Bound to ADO Disconnected Recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007, ado, recordset

I seem to be clueless on this subject. I can attach an ADO recordset to a form, but I am not sure how to handle updates. I don't want to only UpdateBatch, I want to be able to detect what was changed for logging purposes. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The supplied SQL contains one Key field which is an Autonumber named "ID".

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim rst as Object
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    '...edit out connection
    rst.Open sql, mConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic
    set rst.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    Set Me.Recordset =  rst
End Sub 

''Edit records on the form and now click save
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
    Dim rst As Object
    Set rst = Me.Recordset
    Set rst.ActiveConnection = GetConnection
    rst.UpdateBatch
    'How do I detect deleted, added, or modified records for logging? 
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you feel you need to do this? Why not just set the Recordsource property of the form to the appropriate SQL string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use the forms BeforeUpdate and AfterUpdate events to detect additions and edits. As far as Deletes go, you'll need to use the one of the forms delete events:  BeforeDelConfirm, AfterDelConfirm or Delete.

The Dirty event is also handy when it comes to detecting when a user has started editing a record.

I think you really need to make your rst Recordset object a form level object instead of putting it in your Form's Load event.

```
    Dim rst As Object

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    '...edit out connection
    rst.Open sql, mConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic
    set rst.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    'You can close your connection object here now
    Set Me.Recordset =  rst
End Sub 

''Edit records on the form and now click save
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
    Set rst.ActiveConnection = GetConnection
    rst.UpdateBatch
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload()
    'Offer to do batch update here if changes have been made to the recordset
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

You might look into using an AuditTrail function to log changes. However, if the user doesn't perform the batch update, those changes won't actually be made to the database so I'm not sure exactly how you're going to log your changes in a simple, easy manner.

Here's some audit trail code that should work:
http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Creating-an-Audit-Trail-(Source-Code)

I see that Mr. Fenton has questioned why you need a disconnected ADO recordset instead of using MS Access's built-in DAO binding. I do know there are certain situations where an ADO recordset makes sense but I think they are few and far between. Binding to recordsources such as XML files might be one example. I personally like to use it when for binding to a remote SQL Server. It works great for making Access talk to a SQL Server database on your web server out in the cloud. However, you can do this same thing with ODBC tables so there isn't really a compelling reason for using an ADO recordset except that managing DSN's or ODBC table links does have it's challenges.

**Edit1:**
In answer to the OP's concerns about events not catch mass deletions and mass pastes. The Delete event fires for each record selected for deletion and the AfterDelConfirm event fires after the user has pressed "Yes". With paste you are not so lucky as there is no event that fires after the user confirms the paste. One work-around is to disabled additions in the form and use some other method to insert new records.

Another option you might look into is using ADO recordset events. It appears the events will likely do everything except one very critical thing - return a bookmark or primary key for each record that is being edited, deleted, or inserted.

Yet a third option is to set a DateTimeModified for each record. You could then use code at almost any time to iterate through the recordset and log the changes that haven't been logged yet. Simply create a recordset clone and use the recordset's Filter method, something like this:

```
rst.Filter "DateTimeModified > " & LastLoggedDateTime
```

Now iterate through the filtered recordset and log the records. If necessary you could possibly keep a copy of the original recordset in memory (read only) and use it for comparisons. Take a look at this post: [compare two record sets in vb6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860838/compare-two-record-sets-in-vb6)

I do agree that there is no real simple way of doing what you're trying to do. It appears to be fairly complex.

Comment: I appreciate your comments. I would also like to note that this form is going to be displayed in datasheet view. RE Events: The events setup in datasheet view are incomplete and insufficient for logging changes. For instance the user could delete 15 rows and all of the proper events would fire for each row, and then the delete confirmation event would fire after the "are you sure" dialog. However, there is no such setup for multi-row pasting and the "are you sure" dialog for that. That breaks the whole setup for relying on events.

Comment: Have you tested this? I recently had a user use Find&Replace and my Audit Trail function logged every record change. I'm not convinced that there are no catchable events for mass deletions and mass pastes.

Comment: Why would you enable deletions if you don't want them?

Comment: @HK1 Hey man just came back and re-read your answer again after 2 years. I just want to thank you again for such a great response. I really like your date/time modified idea. I still use this method sparingly in my projects, but mainly for display purposes only - showing imported data to the user that they are not allowed to edit and preventing them from opening a linked table or something and editing it there. If the user has admin/edit privileges I will just modify the form's recordset to then point to a linked or local table and manage from there. So much easier that way.