# Save record changes - Access ado form

Tags: ms-access, ado, recordset

Help please!

I've created a database for logging service calls, based on one of Microsoft's templates (Very loosely based now!)

I have a "Case Details" form, which is opened from a case list split form.  Originally, this was opening the form with a filter - which I assume means that it is actually loading the whole recordset?

As I assume (hopefully correctly) that this will be quite inefficient as the database grows, I decided to change the form to open and ADO recordset, using a SQL statement, only selecting the record I want.

The code for this is as follows, and the form opens with the correct record, and I can update the fields.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error GoTo Form_Load_Err

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

If (IsNull(TempVars!currentid)) Then

Me.DataEntry = True

Else
      'Use the ADO connection that Access uses
  Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
  'Create an instance of the ADO Recordset class,
  'and set its properties
  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  With rs
     Set .ActiveConnection = cn
     .Source = "SELECT * FROM Cases WHERE ID = " & TempVars!currentid & ";"
     .LockType = adLockOptimistic
     .CursorLocation = adUseClient
     .CursorType = adOpenStatic
     .Open
  End With
  'Set the form's Recordset property to the ADO recordset
  Set Me.Recordset = rs
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set cn = Nothing

End If

 Call IntializeCollections


Select Case (Me.Status)
   Case 7, 8
     Call EnableControls(mcolgrpAllFields, False)
End Select


Form_Load_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Form_Load_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Form_Load_Exit

End Sub
```

However, here is the problem.  What the blinking heck do I do to save my changes?  I've done some googling, and looked at [MS Access Form Bound to ADO Disconnected Recordset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641760/ms-access-form-bound-to-ado-disconnected-recordset)  but I'm still absolutely stumped.

Is there as simple "save the updates" command? or do I have to iterate through each field, check for changes, then save those changes?

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose that this is too simple, and I should be able to find it on the web?  Can no-one point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update one record at a time try this solution for disconnected recordsets:  http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/how-do-i/how-do-i-pass-data-over-a-network-using-disconnected-recordsets/