# How do you bind userform controls to recordset at runtime?

Tags: vba, ms-access, userform

I have a userform in Access 2013 and I'd like to bind the controls to a ADO recordset when it is opened.

So far, I have the following code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    With cn
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .Properties("Data Source").Value = CurrentProject.FullName
        .Properties("Mode").Value = adModeReadWrite
        .Properties("Persist Security Info").Value = False
        .Open
    End With

       Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

   With rs
      Set .ActiveConnection = cn
      .Source = "SELECT SerialNumber FROM SerialPlateData"
      .LockType = adLockOptimistic
      .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
      .Open
   End With

    'bind textbox to ado recordset at runtime
    txtSerialNumber.ControlSource = rs.Fields("SerialNumber").Name

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

I get an error at this line `txtSerialNumber.ControlSource = rs.Fields("SerialNumber").Name`

My aim is to bind the data retrieved from the recordset to the controls on the userform and when finished, I'll be updating the data table with any changes.

How am I best to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Have to bind form to data set. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641760/ms-access-form-bound-to-ado-disconnected-recordset

Comment: Yup, you can't bind individual controls to different recordsets unless you're willing to do really complicated stuff. I do have code lying around for something similar, but it's very lengthy

Comment: Don't use an Office/Excel Userform. Use an Access form and bind it to the table and the control to the field. _Zero code_.